# Implementing PUT in Java Client application

Tags: java

I’m trying to implement a restful client using Java 
but when I use PUT I keep getting the error here

```
Response response = invocationBuilder.put(Entity.entity(b,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ));
```

I have checked my endpoint in Postman and it’s working fine.

code:

```
public class Book {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

            WebTarget webTarget =client.target("http://localhost:8080/ServerSide/..... ");



            String[] n= new String[1];
            n[0]=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;




            BookInfo b = new BookInfo();
            b.setId(1);
            b.setName("new book");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(n);


Response response = invocationBuilder.put(Entity.entity(b,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ));
```

> ERROR:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class BookInfo, genericType=class BookInfo.
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class BookInfo, genericType=class BookInfo.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:393)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.put(JerseyInvocation.java:326)
    at Book.main(Book.java:53)
```

Comment: try with application_json

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this dependency in your project? Jersey is telling you it doesn't know how to take the entity 'b' and turn it into XML on the wire.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
  <version><!-- version here --></version>
</dependency>
```

This provides the necessary bindings.

Comment: where should i add this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own code you can just use existing 3d party clients. Here are some popular ones:

1. Apache Http Client: See this [link](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
2. OK Http client: See this client: See this [link](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)
3. And finally my favorite one (coming from Open source MgntUtils library written by me): See this javadoc for [HttpClient](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The library itself is available As [Maven Artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.3/jar) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt). Its easy to use and well tested. All you will need to do is to set a value for content type using method `setContentType(String)` if needed and then just call method `sendHttpRequest(String, HttpMethod)` or `sendHttpRequest(String, HttpMethod, String)` (or if the reply is expected to be binary such as image then call the methods `sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse(String, HttpMethod)` or `sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse(String, HttpMethod, String)`)